# Declaring and using function pointers in x86-64 assembly

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86-64, function-pointers

I am trying to understand how to declare and use function pointers in assembly.
In this example I want `call_add` to call `add_fnct`. Which may be passed as a pointer. However when `CALL [rdx]` is executed, it results in an segmentation fault.

```
 MOV rdx, add_fnct
    CALL call_add
    ret
    
add_fnct:
    ADD rdi,rsi
    MOV rax,rdi
    RET  
    
call_add:
    MOV rdi, 5
    MOV rsi, 6
    CALL [rdx]
    RET
```

Comment: RDX is a function pointer, not a pointer to a function-pointer.  Use `call rdx` to do `RIP=RDX`, not `RIP=mem[rdx]`.  Your code doesn't include any "declaration" of a function pointer so IDK what you mean by that part of the title question.  A function pointer is just a 64-bit integer that happens to be the address of some machine code, like usual in asm.  Often you'll get that address as the address of a symbol.